# is there any other way to avoid redrawing for the 2nd viewport?

Tags: c#, xna, camera, draw, viewport

I have to add a second viewport (= like splitscreen) to allow the player to see an event somewhere else on the current level.

Is there any possibility to draw the event area without redrawing every things already drew ?

[EDIT]
RenderTarget2D is the key. Thx User1459910 for all.

It almost worked.

New questions :

1. I've searched for a while and still don't find a tutorial about "Xna 2D camera with source and destination rectangle" if you have a link, i'd like to see it, please ♥
2. Currently, the drawing code looks like this :

   ```
   protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
   {

      /*
      ...
      here is the code to "draw" in the renderTarget2D renderAllScene object
      ...
      */

      //Let's draw into the 2 viewports
      spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, null, null, null, camera1.transform);
      spriteBatch.Draw(renderAllScene, viewport1.Bounds, Color.White);
      spriteBatch.End();
      if (EventIsRunning)
      {
         spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, null, null, null, camera2.transform);
         spriteBatch.Draw(renderAllScene, viewport2.Bounds, Color.White);
         spriteBatch.End();
      }
   ```

*The Viewport 1 is great. The camera follows the character but after moving the camera for a short distance, the map is cutted at 1280pixels i think. so it drew only 1280pixels of all the map. I don't know why. Maybe because i failed when i created renderAllScene = new RenderTarget2D. :x

```
        renderAllScene = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight);
```

*For the Viewport 2 : I need the source rectangle. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Some people said you can actually move the viewport instead of moving all the objects in the world, though I haven't tried that yet myself. I guess basically you need to find out which objects can be seen in both viewports, draw them all with spritebatch, and then do something with your viewports. Or draw stuff for first viewport, then stuff for the other, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are making a 2D game with NOTHING 3D at all.

Here is what you could do:

You need to render the whole map, and all game objects that appear on it, on a Texture. If you don't know how to render to a Texture, here is the procedure:

1. Create a RenderTarget2D object
2. On the Draw function, before you render anything, you must call the graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget() method, and set the RenderTarget2D you created.
3. After you are done rendering, call graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null) to reset the render target to the default one. You must do it or you'll have problems!
4. To render the RenderTarget2D, simply use SpriteBatch.Draw((Texture2D)renderTarget2D, position, color), being "renderTarget2D" of course the name of the RenderTarget2D you created.

Then, you use two 2D Cameras. One will display where the hero is, and the other one will display the event area.

A 2D camera is basically a trick with Source and Destination rectangles. The trick is to use a Source Rectangle to define the area that displays the hero and the area around it and use the main Viewport as the Destination Rectangle, and use another Source Rectangle to define the event area and another Destination Rectangle as the second Viewport.

If you have doubts, google about "XNA 2D Camera", and research about Source and Destination rectangles on the MSDN's article for SpriteBatch.Draw().

Comment: thx for the answer ! i'm a bit tired and not very good in english (so i'll re-read your answer tomorrow). Here are more infos : 1-It's a 2D game but 2-I'm using matrix (with Vector3), will your answer still work ?

Comment: You're using Matrix for what? You mean a transformation Matrix on the SpriteBatch.Begin()? If yes, my answer will still work if you account properly for the Source Rectangle's position and dimensions.

Comment: yes, the camera matrix transformation used in spritebatch.begin().
Thx a lot, i'll try this in few hours ♥

Comment: Then, you should know that the Matrix will transform the position and dimensions of the Destination rectangle (but the Source Rectangle will go untransformed no matter what). Be mindful that if use a different origin and a rotation on the draw call, the position of the Destination rectangle will be screwed up!

Comment: Hum, i think it's a bit tricky because i already use a RenderTarget2D for shadows and lights (and i have to re-display shadows and lights in the 2nd viewport), but i tried some things but without success... I edited to put more infos about my drawing code.
Hope you can still help.

Comment: because there's already a renderTarget2D, i'm lost :x I really have to learn more about these viewports and renderT2D...

Comment: No problem. You can still render the RenderTarget used for shadows on another RenderTarget. The idea is to render the whole map and everything on it once on a Texture, and then render parts of this Texture on screen, one part on one Viewport.

Comment: Ok, i learnt a lot about renderTarget2D. After reading all your comments, just to be sure, I have to : 1. Draw all the scenes in my RenderTarget2D object (= RenderTarget2D renderScene). 2. Draw the shadows and lights on the actual RenderTarget2D (= RenderTarget2D shadowsResolver). 3. Add shadowsResolver in renderScene. 4. Display the entire renderScene in the main viewport. (with SetRenderTarget(null). 5. Display the rectangle area where the event is in the second viewport (with SetRenderTarget(null). Am I right ? i'll try it.

Comment: It almost worked ^^.
I edited the main post with new questions if you can answer it... Thx a lot

Comment: 1. I see you are using a Matrix to dislocate the sprites. Using a Matrix for such ends is pretty much an overkill. You should use a Matrix for making more difficult things such as scaling or rotating. The principle of a 2D Camera using Rectangles is that the camera is actually just a Source Rectangle whose position is the camera's position and the dimensions are the camera's field of view. The world the 2D Camera "films" is a Texture containing the whole world and objects on it, generated by an usual render-to-texture procedure.

Comment: One common issue when making 2D cameras is dealing with the situations when the camera looks at an off-map region. There are two ways you can deal with it:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23602/discussion-between-user1459910-and-sharpnel)